# How to add trigger for s3 event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, serverless-architecture

How to add a trigger for an s3 folder?

I can add triggers for a bucket from my serverless configuration.

But not sure how to add a trigger for a folder path?

```
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: files          
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          existing: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to setup a `prefix` as shown in the [docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3/):

```
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: files          
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          existing: true
          rules:
            - prefix: your-folder/
```

Comment: Is there a way to exclude a folder?

Comment: @Exploring Sadly, there is not. You can move the folder to other bucket if possible.